# Link icon jumps below parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create an `<li>` in which two elements are located, an `<a>` with `<span>` and a second `<a>` that holds a variable, `html`. However, the variable, which is a glyphicon, jumps down below the other `<a>`. How can I fix this?

```
var html = "<a href=\"#\" id='removeBtn' class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></a>";
$('#conversations').append("<li id=" + id + "><a href=\"#\" class=\"list-group-item\"><span>" + conversation.name + "</span></a>" + html + "</li>");
```

Comment: This wouldn't happen by default so it must be to do with the CSS set on those elements, most likely `display: block` or `clear: both`

Comment: I haven't used either display: block or clear: both.

Comment: You may not have, but it could be in the glyphicon CSS file

Comment: Could you list the styles attached to those elements? Also, you can use single quotes in your 'html' variable id instead of escaping the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have put the class definition on the wrong item.  I moved it over to the li.

```js
html="test"
id="6"
conversation={name:"bob"}
var html = "<a href=\"#\" id='removeBtn' class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></a>";
$('#conversations').append("<li class=\"list-group-item\" id=" + id + "><a href=\"#\" ><span>" + conversation.name + "</span></a>" + html + "</li>");
```

```css
li {
  list-style-type:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="conversations"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I change the tag of the glyphicon to button instead of a. Solved the issue. Sorry for the inconvenience